# If your World of Warcraft subcriptions runs out could you still play on that character?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have 28 days left and I just want to know if I can still play my character after my subscription runs out.

Answer (score 7):

## No

Once your subscription runs out you cannot play *any* characters at all. They will become available again once you renew your subscription.

You won't lose any progress made if you are not subscribed for some time. You can't play *at all* during the period that you are not subscribed.

Comment: In fact, it will boot you while you're playing. I neglected to update my information when I was issued a new card and was booted in the middle of a dungeon. Frustrating, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot play the main game without the subscription, you can still play the Public Test Realm, and copy over characters to PTR as well, it's not as fun but it's still there if you don't want to get rusty over your subscription break.